# 'ItemIterator' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, twitter

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm).items(NoOfTerms)
tweets.to_csv("new.csv")
```

While running the code to write a csv file from the extracted tweets from twitter, i'm getting the error as,

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 tweets.to_csv("new.csv")
>
> AttributeError: 'ItemIterator' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

How could i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job!

I will recommend you to use csv from Python. Open a file and write to it during your loop like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX')
auth.set_access_token('XXX-XXX', 'XXX')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q = "google",
                           since = "2014-02-14",
                           until = "2014-02-15",
                           lang = "en").items():

    # Write a row to the CSV file. I use encode UTF-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `tweepy.Cursor(...).items()` returns an iterator. This iterator has no method `to_csv()`. Instead, you want to iterate over the items of the `Cursor` object:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm).items(NoOfTerms):
    # process tweet here
    process_tweet(tweet)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time mate!! But i'm a beginner in python, so i couldn't get what u are trying to say. Anyways thanks!!